# Error in Proof of Residues?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, roots

I wanted to prove that the function

$$F(z) = \frac{z-\sum_{j =2}^{n-1} z^j}{1-\sum_{k=1}^{n}  z^k} $$ 
will only contain simple poles. Is the following proof correct?

[image]

Which implies that $z_o$ has order $1$.[image]

Since I know that this proof isn't fully true, does anyone have any suggestions? Or new methods of proving it?

Comment: Could you explain the chain of equalities above "this implies that"?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Since $\mathfrak{f}(z_o) \neq 0$ (it equals one), the derivative of $\mathfrak{f}(z) $ at $z_o$ cannot equal zero, therefore $\alpha = 1$

Comment: @AntonioVargas $z_o$ is a zero of the function $1-\mathfrak{f}(z)$,which implies that $z_o$ must satisfy the equation $\mathfrak{f}(z_o) = 1$ in order for $z_o$ to be a zero of $1-\mathfrak{f}(z)$.

Comment: Are you saying that $f(z_0) = 1$ implies that $f'(z_0) = 1$, or something like that?

Comment: For example, take $$f(z) = z+z^2+2z^3.$$ Then $1-f(z)$ has a zero at $z=1/2$ but $$\left.\frac{d(1-f(z))}{dz}\right|_{z=1/2} = \left[-1-2z-6z^2\right]_{z=1/2} = -\frac{7}{2} \neq 1.$$

Comment: I just noticed the flaw in this proof. it was correct when all of the coefficients were one, but must be changed otherwise. Let me revise it

Comment: @AntonioVargas I had to edit it to only the case where the coefficients are 1

Comment: Okay so you assume that $$-1 -2z_0 -3z_0^2 - \cdots - nz_0^{n-1} = 0$$ and add $1$ to both sides.  Fine.  Now $1 = g(z_0) = z_0 + z_0^2 + \cdots + z_0^n$ by definition of $z_0$, so you have $$-2z_0 -3z_0^2 - \cdots - nz_0^{n-1} = z_0 + z_0^2 + \cdots + z_0^n.$$  Note the typo here in your argument.  And if we move everything to one side this is equivalent to $$0 = 3z_0 + 4z_0^2 + \cdots + (n+1)z_0^{n-1} + z_0^n.$$  But how does this imply that $z_0 = 0$?

Comment: By the way, phrases like "we can quite easily deduce that" almost always hide a flaw in an argument or a nontrivial problem that the author could not overcome.  Don't write things like that!

Comment: @AntonioVargas I see your point. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Can you say that it implies that $z_o$ CAN be 0 and therefore the whole thing is a contradiction?

Comment: No, you would have to say that $z_0$ must be $0$.  I don't see how to continue your method and a different method isn't coming to mind.  I will think about it--it's a good problem.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Alright, thank you.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Any luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is whether the polynomial $ 1 - \sum_{k=1}^n z^k = \dfrac{z^{n+1} - 2 z + 1}{1-z}$ has a multiple root.  Since $z=1$ is not a multiple root, this is equivalent (for $n>1$) to whether $z^{n+1} - 2 z + 1$ has a multiple root, i.e. whether there is
$z$ with $z^{n+1} - 2 z + 1 = 0$ and $(n+1) z^n - 2 = 0$.  But if $z^n = \dfrac{2}{n+1}$ we have
$$z^{n+1} - 2 z + 1 = z \left(\frac{2}{n+1} - 2\right) + 1 = \dfrac{-2n}{n+1} z + 1$$ so this would say $z =  \dfrac{n+1}{2n}$.
If $p$ is a prime dividing $n$, then $\dfrac{n+1}{2n}$ is a rational number whose denominator (in lowest terms) is divisible by $p$, and so is  any positive integer power of $\dfrac{n+1}{2n}$, but that is not the case for $2/(n+1)$ (note that $n+1$ and $n$ can't both be divisible by the same prime).

Comment: It is sufficient that the denominator have only simple roots. But that's not necessary for the rational function to have only simple poles. What you seem to say. Unless my english is playing me some tricks...

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Robert Israel's argument proves that.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter What do you mean by "a more original proof"?